# Are these iptables rules necessary?

Tags: iptables

Scenario: Linux based router (Asuswrt-Rmerlin 380.65) running iptables v1.4.14 with the following rules at the top. The purpose of the router is to provide Internet access to internal clients. No services are open for public use on the wanface.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i vlan2 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i vlan2 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

1) With the rules above, is it necessary to have the rules below ?

```
#Drop XMAS packets
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp  --tcp-flags ALL ALL  -j DROP

#Drop NULL packets
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp  --tcp-flags ALL NONE  -j DROP
```

2) Aren't the rules below unnecessary given that OS and netfilter developers already know what to allow / disallow ?

```
#Force SYN packets check
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

#Force Fragments packets check
iptables -I INPUT -f -j DROP
```

Comment: Your first two rules do not represent a "default deny policy". If you want a default deny policy then use -P drop

Comment: This is at the top of the rules - didn't copy and paste.

   iptables -P INPUT DROP

Comment: You are dropping a bunch of things. What are you *accepting*? If all you want to do is drop everything that hits your router on the floor, just `iptables -F INPUT` and `iptables -P INPUT DROP` should be enough, but it won't be very *useful*.

Comment: This is getting off topic, but the default configuration is to DROP NEW incoming connections over the wanface. Other rules, not listed, allow ESTABLISHED and RELATED connections over the wanface on the INPUT chain. My two questions were related to relevance given the posture noted above.

Comment: The complete firewall is relevant because iptables rules are processed in order and the first match wins. Attempting to answer this without understanding the complete firewall could result in you receiving bad advice.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Hampton is dead right, answering questions in the absence of the whole ruleset can be misleading, but we can still make some definitive statements.

You say your ruleset starts with

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i vlan2 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i vlan2 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

then you ask about the rationale for having certain additional rules, looking to find out what they add that the first two rules do not.  Let's take those one by one.

```
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp  --tcp-flags ALL ALL  -j DROP
```

This rule is unrestricted by interface, so it applies to *all* `INPUT` traffic, unlike the first two. It filters out [Christmas Tree packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_packet).  These packets  are malfeasors, ie there is no good reason for them to be on the wire, so filtering them out is a reasonable thing to do.

```
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp  --tcp-flags ALL NONE  -j DROP
```

Similarly, no TCP packet should have *no* flags set, so this is another basic network health line, which again is unrestricted by interface.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

No packet which isn't a SYN packet should match state `NEW`, that is, no SYN packets should be turning up in the middle of established TCP streams.  Refuse any which do; another network health check.

```
iptables -I INPUT -f -j DROP
```

Refuse fragments.  I'm not sure that's a good idea, but some do.

You might ask why bother with these rules if the policy is `DROP` anyway.  The answer is that you have other, later rules which `ACCEPT` traffic, and these might match and thus `ACCEPT` the malicious traffic the rules above affect, had it not already been refused by the explicit `DROP` rules you list.

Comment: Madhatter - Thanks for the detailed response. The questions could have been better worded. The first question should have been, "Given the above rules, would the DROP XMAS and DROP NULL rules ever be processed if vlan2 is the only interface involved ?". The second question is really about old, but at one time useful rules that should have been depracated given 'NIX developers have gotten better at determining what is valid traffic.

Comment: Yes, even if `vlan2` is the only interface on the box, traffic can still fail to match those two rules that relate to it and go on to be caught by the network-health lines I discuss above.  In fact, I can't think of a packet that *would* match the two `vlan2` rules that would also match *any* of those network-health rules.

Comment: At one time, I asked for iptables rules recommendations and the above rules were suggested. I wasn't sure if these types of rules were still relevant since Admins have a tendency to keep older rules around even though developers have improved traffic processing and security.

Comment: Has your question been answered?